# JQuery Mobile Table

Tags: mobile-website, jquery-mobile

Can anyone point me to any sample or can provide any sample of a Jquery Mobile table please?

I've seen the demos on their website and found no tables.

I need to be able to create a table that will look good on Mobile / iPad.

Comment: What do you want beyond `<table>...</table>`?

Comment: I basically want it to be style as JQuery Mobile.

Comment: Consider using something like a [list](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/lists/index.html) instead of a table.

Comment: I thought about it but in my project I need headings (THEAD) and columns so that's why I thought about using tables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Try this layout instead**

```html
<ul>
<li> <!--first item -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Heading1</td>
            <td>Meaning1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Heading2</td>
            <td>Meaning2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Heading3</td>
            <td>Meaning3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</li>
<li> <!-- second item -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Heading1</td>
            <td>Meaning1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Heading2</td>
            <td>Meaning2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Heading3</td>
            <td>Meaning3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</li>
</ul>
```

**and the css**

```
ul {
    width: 100%;    
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
```

*fixed small bugs but have to add this to make substantial edit

Answer (score 14):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/../../docs/content/content-html.html right click and view source:

```html
<table summary="This table lists all the JetBlue flights."> 
  <caption>Travel Itinerary</caption> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
       <th scope="col">Flight:</th>  
      <th scope="col">From:</th>  
      <th scope="col">To:</th>  
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tfoot> 
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="5">Total: 3 flights</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tfoot> 
  <tbody> 
  <tr> 
    <th scope="row">JetBlue 983</th> 
    <td>Boston (BOS)</td> 
    <td>New York (JFK)</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th scope="row">JetBlue 354</th> 
    <td>San Francisco (SFO)</td> 
    <td>Los Angeles (LAX)</td> 
  </tr> 
<tr> 
    <th scope="row">JetBlue 465</th> 
    <td>New York (JFK)</td> 
    <td>Portland (PDX)</td> 
  </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    table { width:100%; }
    table caption { text-align:left;  }
    table thead th { text-align:left; border-bottom-width:1px; border-top-width:1px; }
    table th, td { text-align:left; padding:6px;} 
</style>
```

Updating the Links:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-html.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/branches/swipe/docs/tables/index.html ( beta )

Comment: The table is rendered without jQM theme styling. So this only proves hte OP can't use a table.

Comment: @Potatoswatter this is what jQM Provides for Tables ( currently ) http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-html.html ( view the source ) There is an effort for future a release: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/swipe/docs/tables/index.html

Answer (score 1):

And if you want a crazy alternative you can always create a listview with grids in it. It might look interesting.

Comment: FYI - This appraoch turns into some of the ugliest most un-maintainable HTML you've ever seen, in a hurry.

Comment: This might be true in your case. I have used this idea (but the other way around - a grid with listviews in it) in a page and I was happy with the result.