# How to display query data in jQuery Mobile easily?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile web page with an Inset List that is wrapped in a HTML form. When the action is Submit, the POST parameters are validated in a corresponding file. An SQL query uses these parameters to extract data as per user's actions.

I was wondering, how I can display this query data in a tabular format which has about 8 columns.

Note: This application is actually used on desktop PCs only.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: OP, Can you provide an example of the type of query data you would be displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the target devices, orientations, or size and type of data your are trying to display I would say that you can still use HTML `table` tags.  If you want some jQuery Mobile type styling, [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723036/jquery-mobile-table) may help.

The response on [this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/displaying-tabular-data) explains some great reasons why you may want to reconsider displaying the data in a columnar fashion.

Is is possible to reconsider how much data to display or using something like collapsible sets? Otherwise you probably just want to stick it in the 8 column table and expect the user to scroll horizontally and vertically.